# Is it possible to build v142 project with v143 build tools?

Tags: c++, msbuild

The problem is following:

- One of our VS C++ project files is for v142 build tools and it succesfully buildable with MS Build Tool 2019 on our 'build machine'
- but locally (and also on 'build machines' for other customers) I need to build the same VS C++ project with MS Build Tool 2022 (which use v143 build tools)

Is it possible to build VS C++ v142 project with newer version is MS Build Tools?

So, I want to keep the same VS C++ project file but have it buildable with
MS Build Tools 2019 and 2022. Is it possible at all?

Comment: You could probably use a property file local to each machine which defines the version

Comment: Ok... I just tried to add TreatAsLocalProperty="PlatformToolset" attribute to my *.vcxproj file, then added /p:PlatformToolset=v143 cmdline option for msbuild - but it is still failing with the same error- "error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2019 (Platform Toolset = 'v142') cannot be found". :-\ Maybe PlatformToolset property cannot be overriden?...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about a DLL or static library with a v142 toolkit and you want to use it as a dependency of a project (DLL or EXE) with other toolkits, there are several cases:

- if the dependant is a static library, both must use the same toolkit, because the static lib must be linked with the same toolkit it has been compiled for.
- if the dependant is a DLL that exposes C++ types, (like `std::string`, `std::list` etc.) in its API; (`dllexport`) the toolkit of both projects must be the same, since the types aren't the same when using other toolkit.
- if all DLL exported types are atomics (like integers, or pointers) each can be compiled with a different toolkit.

Changing the toolkit is not a big issue, if you need to compile it on both toolkits, duplicate the debug and release configuration, and change the toolkit for the new configurations.